# how to get url parameter in controller in laravel?

Tags: php, laravel

my view blade .....

```
  tableHtml += "<td><a href= '{{url('/add')}}/" + data.hits[i].recipe.label + "'> add to favotite</a></td>";
```

when i click add to fav....i get this in url

http://localhost/lily/public/add/Chilli%20Green%20Salad

web.php

```
Route::get('/add', 'HomeController@add');
```

how can i get the url pass name in controller .....

```
public function add(Request $request)
{
 
$request->get("") ////////////how can i get the string i passed on url 

}
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You need to add the parameter to the route. So, it should look like this:

```
Route::get('add/{slug}', 'HomeController@add');
```

And the `add` method:

```
public function add(Request $request, $slug)
```

Then value of the `$slug` variable will be `Chilli Green Salad`

https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/routing#required-parameters

Answer (score 4):

You can do it like,

**Route**

```
Route::get('add/{data}', 'HomeController@add');
```

**Controller**

```
public function add(Request $request){
    // Access data variable like $request->data
}
```

I hope you will understand.

Comment: url parameter can be accessed through request so what's the problem ? can you explain please :D

Comment: I've used it a lot of times and works do you mean bad practice then okay :)

Answer (score 2):

Alter your url,add a get variabile

```
tableHtml += "<td><a href= '{{url('/add')}}/?slug=" + data.hits[i].recipe.label + "'> add to favotite</a></td>";
```

in your controller you use

```
public function add(Request $request)
{

echo $request->slug;

}
```

Answer (score 1):

In your `router.php`:

```
Route::get('/add/{recipe}', 'HomeController@add'); // if recipe is required
Route::get('/add/{recipe?}', 'HomeController@add'); // if recipe is optional
```

In your `controller:

```
public function add(Request $request, $recipe) {
  // play with $recipe
}
```

Hope this will help!

Comment: this is a variation of Alexey's answer

Answer (score 0):

1. If you have your parameter attached to the URL after the question mark like

> http://www.siteurl.com/someRoute?key=value

Your route for this controller will look something like this

```
public function controllerMethod(Request $request) {
$key = $request->key
echo $key;
}
```

2. If you have your parameter attached to the URL without question mark like

> http://www.siteurl.com/someRoute/value

Your route for this controller will look something like this

```
Route::get('someRoute/{key}', $controller . 'controllerMethod');
```

You can get the value of this parameter in your controller function by passing the same name of variable in your controller method as you used in the route.

```
public function controllerMethod(Request $request, $key) {
echo $key;
}
```